# Selection sorting strings on a struct

Tags: c, sorting, struct

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void sort_names();


struct ListNames {

    char names[20];
    int age;

}n[6] = {

    {"Ryan, Elizabeth",62},
    {"McIntyre, Osborne",84},
    {"DuMond, Kristin",18},
    {"Larson, Lois",42},
    {"Thorpe, Trinity",15},
    {"Ruiz, Pedro",35},  

};

int main (void) {
    int i;
    printf("Original List");
    printf("\n-----------------------------");

    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        printf("\n%-20s",n[i].names);
        printf("      %2i",n[i].age);
    }


}
```

I am trying to sort the strings in the struct in alphabetical order, along with the int with the string. I am able to print it fine, but I am clueless on what to do next on calling the struct to sort it in alphabetical order. I know i am going to need an index value but I dont know how i would do that within a struct.

Comment: It's very simple: you just need to implement `sort_names();` ;-)

Comment: @BlueMoon what do you mean sort_names() can you be more specific?

Comment: The function prototype you have in your code...

Comment: @BlueMoon I'm not following you dude.... implement that function onto n?

Comment: @hello world It would be better if the last and first names were  separated that is would be stored in different character arrays.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow but that would just be more work wouldnt it? My assignment is instructed this way anwayys

Comment: It sounds like you are confusing yourself.  You cannot  "sort the strings in the struct", because each `struct` contains exactly one string.  You do have an array of multiple `struct`s, however, and it seems that what you actually want to do is sort *those* according to their `names` fields.  You have already demonstrated in your print loop that you know how to index into that array.

Comment: @JohnBollinger thanks for clarifying, so how would I go about sorting those structs in alphabetical order?

Comment: @hello world Also I would declare function sort_names like void sort_names( ListNames *list, size_t n );

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over your entire list while keeping track of the smallest element.By smallest i mean by name.That element(name and age) is then swapped by the element at first position.Then the second smallest element is replace by element at second position in similar fashion.

```
int is_smaller(char *a,char *b)//returns true if a<b
{

if(strcmp(a,b)<0)
    return 1;
else
    return 0;
}
void swap(char* a,char* b)//to swap names
{
    char arr[100];
    strcpy(arr,a);
    strcpy(a,b);
    strcpy(b,arr);
}
void swap(int &a,int &b)//to swap age
{
    int temp=a;
    a=b;
    b=temp;
}  
int smallest;
for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
{
    smallest=i;
    for(int j=i+1;j<6;j++)
    if(!is_smaller(n[smallest].names,n[j].names))//is smaller return true if first argument is smaller than second
    {
        smallest=j;
    }
    if(smallest!=i)
    {
        swap(n[i].names,n[smallest].names);
        swap(n[i].age,n[smallest].age);
    }
}
```

Comment: it looks good, but I am confused on how to implement this? Ive tried adding this into my main function but no good.

Comment: thank you for updating, am i throwing all of this into the main function? sorry for the late response!

Comment: For good design, keep `is_smaller()` and `swap()` functions out of `main()`.